# Dynamically execute a method only once a day using webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-3.5

I want to create a webservice which will process the data in my database once in a day at a particular time.

This time will be stored in a database.

It should only run once a day.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), make it start when Windows starts, set up a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), create an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to handle the timer's [elapsed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and you're good to go.

Comment: Way overkill, IMHO. Schedulers are a dime a dozen.

Comment: @Seva possibly overkill, but based on the information that @PARTH provided, I understood that he wants an automated process.

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev - .NET services are so clean, easy, and flexible it's hard to call them overkill. If the operation is simplistic I would opt for the Windows task scheduler, but as soon as it needs logic I would create a Windows service.

Comment: Creating yet another task scheduler? Come on. These things tend to grow requirements, as time goes by. At some point they'll want more than one task. Then they'll want tasks that are other than Web service calls. Then impersonation. And PARTH will end up with an inferior clone of one of the existing schedulers, EXCEPT he's paid the price of custom development rather than using the ready-made thing. Not Invented Here syndrome, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Web Services are not appropriate for this task. They are meant to run in response to a request. You need code to run in response to the time of day.

I agree with the suggestion to create a Windows Service. If you don't want to do that, then create a simple Console application, and run it via Scheduled Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary that time is stored in the database? Typically, they use an external scheduler service (Task Scheduler or SQL Agent) for that. And invoke the service by running a command-line HTTP client with a service URL. Curl would work, for example, or you can put together a quick JavaScript with an XMLHTTP call and invoke it with cscript.exe.

Also, if the data processing can be completely implemented as a stored procedure, there's no need for Web services and shell scripts. Call the procedure directly from SQL Agent (assuming MS SQL Server).

EDIT: then you've complicated the design considerably. Say, how precise a timing do you want? Do you want the time to be precise to one minute, one hour, one day? If the desired precision is something along the lines of several minutes, here's what you can do. Have a procedure in the database. Have it executed (via SQL Agent) on the precision boundary - say, every 5 minutes. Have it check if now's the time to run the service. If so, have it invoke the service. XMLHTTP and OLE automation is probably the way to go; look up system procedures sp_OACreate, sp_OAMethod. Something like this:

```
declare @o int
exec sp_OACreate 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP', @o output
exec sp_OAMethod @o, 'open', @bstrMethod='GET', @bstrUrl='http://what-have-you/'
exec sp_OAMethod @o, 'send'
```

Procedures sp_OAxxx are considered, rightfully, very unsafe and there require considerable privilege level to run.

Comment: Yeah time will be set in database. No the data processing cannot be implemented as a stored proc. so I need a webservice. So how can I do it using webservice